# Can we nominate someone for Moderator besides ourself?

Tags: discussion, election

I would like to be able to do this, but I can't see any way to do so on the [election page](https://biology.stackexchange.com/election?cb=1).  Any pointers?

Comment: just suggest that person that you would like to support them. unless you want to nominate person for job they don't want...

Answer (score 5):

No, you can't. The only person you can nominate is yourself. As @aandreev mentioned in his comment, it wouldn't be a good idea to nominate people who doesn't want this job. If you have a candidate in mind, you can ask them in chat (or probably also in the thread in meta) if they want to be a candidate.